# ASP.NET Identity Caching User

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using ASP.NET Identity in MVC 5, I am looking to provide a Change Password page...

Within my Controller I call into the ChangePasswordAsync() method provided by the ASP.Net.Identity.Core which then hooks into my Service and successfully changes the password for the user on the database. This is all well and good, however I realise there maybe certain situations where I need to handle exceptions from the service. Therefore I have wrapped a try catch around the ChangePasswordAsync() which will return back to the initial Change Password page with an error message if anything goes wrong.

Now my issue is that if an exception is thrown within the service prior to the database update of the password, the new password is still cached in memory. Therefore when the user attempts to change their password again after the failure, it shows an Incorrect Password error message.

Does anyone know if there is a way to ensure that the user only gets cached upon the successful return of the service and doesn't get cached if an exception occurs?

Comment: Can you add some code examples?